# Any way to intercept typed function calls in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, proxy, decorator

I know that it's an easy thing to do with a function dynamically added to a dynamic proxy class, but I'd love to be able to intercept the calls to a typed function too, like you can with decorators in Python.  Example below.  I'd love some way to be able to go through 'callProperty' for 'typedFunc' like it already goes through 'dynFunc',

[image: example]

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    [SWF(width = '400', height = '400')]
    public class Test extends Sprite
    {
        public function Test()
        {
            var t:TypeTest = new TypeTest();
            t.dynFunc = function dynFunc(s:String, i:int):Boolean { return true; };

            t.typedFunc("a", 1);
            t.dynFunc("b", 2);
        }
    }
}
import flash.utils.Proxy;
import flash.utils.flash_proxy;

internal dynamic class TypeTest extends Proxy
{
    private var customs:Object = new Object();
    override flash_proxy function callProperty(name:*, ...parameters):* {
        var retval:* = (this[name] as Function).apply(null, parameters);
        trace("called", name, "with", parameters);
        return retval;
    }
    public function typedFunc(s:String, i:int):Boolean {
        return false;
    }
    override flash_proxy function getProperty(name:*):* { return customs[name]; }
    override flash_proxy function setProperty(name:*, value:*):void { customs[name] = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not easy to do in ActionScript, because the compiler won't allow you to alter a sealed class' method at runtime using "regular" ActionScript language constructs - so you won't be able to alter the behavior of the original class. Period.

Luckily, there is the [as3commons:bytecode](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/emit.html) library. You can use it to generate a dynamic proxy class at runtime: It generates a byte array representation of the class and loads it into the AVM, so you can use it like any other class.  It might even be possible to use the original class as a blueprint and replace it with a modified version, but I have to admit I haven't tried that.